# Keep classes anonymous in TicTacToe program

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, tic-tac-toe

[My console TicTacToe program](https://github.com/iceblu3710/odin_tictactoe)

This is my first large project attempt and I want to learn how to keep classes as anonymous as reasonable and as protected/secure as reasonable.

The program works as intended and I think it meets the requirements but can you guys share some pointers?

```
class TicTacToe
    WINNING_SCORES = [7,56,448,73,146,292,84,273]
    SCORE_HASH = {0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 4,
                             3 => 8, 4 => 16, 5 => 32,
                             6 => 64, 7 => 128, 8 => 256}

    class Player
            attr_reader         :mark
            attr_accessor :score
            attr_accessor :turn

            def initialize(player_mark)
                    @mark = player_mark
                    @score = 0
                    @turn = 0
            end
    end

    def initialize(player1_char, player2_char)
            @player1 = Player.new(player1_char)
            @player2 = Player.new(player2_char)
            set_turn()
            setup_board()
            display_board()
            greet_player()
    end

    def go(spot)
            player_mark = get_player()
            if fill_spot?(spot, player_mark)
                    update_score()
                    next_turn()
                    display_board()
                    greet_player()
            end
    end

    private
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def setup_board
            @gameboard = []
            9.times { @gameboard << " " }
    end

    def set_turn()
            @player1.turn = rand(2)
            @player2.turn = 1 unless @player1.turn == 1
    end

    def update_score
            @player1.score = calculate_score(@player1.mark)
            @player2.score = calculate_score(@player2.mark)
            congrats(@player1.mark) if winner?(@player1.score)
            congrats(@player2.mark) if winner?(@player2.score)
    end

    def congrats(player)
            display_board()
            puts "\n\n\t CONGRAGULATIONS PLAYER #{player}, YOU WON!\n\n"
            exit()
    end

    def calculate_score(mark)
            score = 0
            @gameboard.each_with_index do |char, i|
                    score += SCORE_HASH[i] if char == mark
            end
            score
    end

    def winner?(player_score)
            WINNING_SCORES.each do |score|
                    return true if player_score & score == score
            end
            false
    end

    def display_board
            puts "\n\n\t TicTacToe \n\n"
            puts "        1|2|3 \t #{@gameboard[0]}|#{@gameboard[1]}|#{@gameboard[2]}"
            puts "        ------ \t ------"
            puts "        4|5|6 \t #{@gameboard[3]}|#{@gameboard[4]}|#{@gameboard[5]}"
            puts "        ------ \t ------"
            puts "        7|8|9 \t #{@gameboard[6]}|#{@gameboard[7]}|#{@gameboard[8]}"
            puts "\n"
    end

    def greet_player
            player_mark = get_player()
            puts "\t#{player_mark}'s turn!"
    end

    def next_turn
            @player1.turn, @player2.turn = @player2.turn, @player1.turn
    end

    def fill_spot?(spot, player_mark)
            if @gameboard[spot-1] == " " then
                    @gameboard[spot-1] = player_mark
                    return true
            else
                    spot_taken()
                    display_board()
                    greet_player()
                    return false
            end
    end

    def spot_taken
            puts "\n\n\t That spot is already taken!"
    end

    def get_player
            return @player1.mark if @player1.turn == 1
            return @player2.mark if @player2.turn == 1
            raise NoPlayerFound "Neither player's turn is set!"
    end
end

game = TicTacToe.new("X","O")

loop do
    print "Choose spot (1..9): "
    choice = gets.chomp.to_i
    game.go(choice) if choice.between?(1,9)
end
```

Comment: Can you post some code that we can review

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review.  For various reasons, it's required to post the code that you want reviewed in the question.  You can also post a link if it provides additional context, but we only review posted code not linked code.

Comment: I'll post a snippit but its ~130lines linked.

Answer (score 1):

```
def setup_board
  @gameboard = []
  9.times { @gameboard << " " }
end
```

Can just be:

```
@gameboard = Array.new(9){ " " }
```

---

It is idiomatic in Ruby to omit parentheses when not needed, e.g. `display_board` instead of `display_board()`.

---

```
def winner?(player_score)
  WINNING_SCORES.each do |score|
    return true if player_score & score == score
  end
  false
end
```

Instead:

```
def winner?(player_score)
  WINNING_SCORES.any?{ |score| player_score & score == score }
end
```

(I'm trusting that the bitwise AND logic you have there is correct.)

---